# Fuzzy attribute search (fuzzy logic search) in Solr

Tags: solr, information-retrieval, fuzzy-search, fuzzy-logic

I want to be able to submit a query like this:

```
car AND (color:blue AND price:[* TO 10000] AND model:Toyota)
```

and retrieve results like this (assuming these are the most relevant results):

```
{name : "An old car", color: "blue", price: "6000", model : "Toyota"}
{name : "An old car", color: "red", price: "5000", model : "Toyota"}
{name : "Another old car", color: "blue", price: "9000", model : "Volvo"}
{name : "Another old car", color: "white", price: "11000", model : "Toyota"}
```

In other words, fuzzy search, but not on the string level but on the "faceting level". I want it work so that articles that match all the requirements always get up top but articles that only match a subset still get retrieved.

Does Solr or any other search framework have support for this? Can I accomplish this using query boosting for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it can be done by modifying the query somewhat like this (newlines added for readability); although I'm not sure about the boost syntax:

```
(car AND (color:blue^0.9 OR color:[* TO *]^0.1) 
     AND (price:[* TO 10000]^0.9 OR price:[* TO *]^0.1) 
     AND (model:Toyota^0.9 OR model:[* TO *]^0.1))
```

#### Edit:

This solution seems to work quite as I intended in my implementation. Although I added to the weights for the preferred properties. ^1000 seemed to give them enough weight to win over the non preferred.

Comment: Boost will change your order so model:Toyota^0.9 OR color:blue^0.5 does mean if there is a blue Mercedes and a red Toyota, the Toyota entries will be on top of the Mecedes ones

Comment: This seems overly complicated. Simply create an or query with each of those filters and add car to a filter query (or prefix with a + to ensure it matches). In or queries, solr will prefer documents that match more filters than those that match less.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a url query, for example in the admin frontend a query looks like this:

```
q=car&fq=color:blue&fq=price:[* TO 10000]&fq=model:Toyota
```

Or maybe for your example it is

```
q=*&fq=name:car&fq=color:blue&fq=price:[* TO 10000]&fq=model:Toyota
```

Now the results depend on the configured logic operator which can be configured in the schema.xml, default operator is AND, see here:

[Schema documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Default_query_parser_operator)

For a single field a filterquery is like a String.contains() function in java.

Comment: It seems that I can just as well write `q=(name:car AND color:blue AND model:Toyota)` although judging by the documentation specifying field queries could give some speedups. It would be nice to have a F_AND operator here, for "fuzzy AND". That's what I'm looking for. So that Mercedes and red cars will not get excluded but get a lower score.

Comment: Also. I think I have avoided fq so far since it messes with json and ajax calls. I would need to write workaround for "having an object where one field is defined multiple times".

Comment: Does the OR-Operator fit your needs?

Comment: Well, the OR operator doesn't set a higher score if it happens to fit both parameters (I assume). So it's neither AND or OR, it's fuzzy logic.

Comment: To clarify a bit, the and operator means when having some filterqueries like name and model both have to match. The or operator is for one of the filters have to match. Match means for text fields, the the searchterm is contained in the content of the field.